# XDocument Descendants() displays all child values in the parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

This is the XML to be parsed, using XDocument:

```
<e xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FormValues />
  <Others>
    <Bank>
      <Key>FirstKey</Key>
      <Value>FirstValue</Value>
    </Bank>
    <Bank>
      <Key>SecondKey</Key>
      <Value>SecondValue</Value>
    </Bank>
    <Bank>
      <Key>ThirdKey</Key>
      <Value>ThirdValue</Value>
    </Bank>
    <Bank>
      <Key>FourthKey</Key>
      <Value>FourthValue</Value>
    </Bank>
  </Others>
  <Prob>ProbValue</Prob>
  <URL>http://example.com/</URL>
  <Method>GET</Method>
</e>
```

If I do:

```
string doc = "<e xmlns:xsd..> ..... </e>";
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument docNew = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(doc);
var elements = docNew.Root.Descendants();
@foreach (var element in elements)
{
    <label>@element.Name.ToString():</label><span>@element.Value.ToString()</span>
}
```

It displays:

```
FormValues:
Others: FirstKeyFirstValueSecondKeySecondValueThirdKeyThirdValueFourthKeyFourthValue
Bank : FirstKeyFirstValue
Key  : FirstKey
Value: FirstValue
Bank : SecondKeySecondValue
Key  : SecondKey
Value: SecondValue
Bank : ThirdKeyThirdValue
Key  : ThirdKey
Value: ThirdValue
Bank : FourthKeyFourthValue
Key  : FourthKey
Value: FourthValue
Prob : ProbValue
URL  : http://example.com/
Method:GET
```

I only want the Key and Value Nodes to display the value.
Like:

```
Others
Bank
Key  : FirstKey
Value: FirstValue
Bank
Key  : SecondKey
Value: SecondValue
....
```

Comment: With Descendants() you have XPath then: `.Descendants("Key or Value")` or in this case also `.Descendants(Key|Value)`.

Comment: var elementsKey = docNew.Root.Descendants("Key"); Then foreach loop will only have Keys. How can I include, var elementsValue = docNew.Root.Descendants("Value"); as well?

Comment: Using `Descendants("Key or Value")` or `Descendants("Key|Value")`. Note `or` logical or operator and `|` union operator.

Comment: Error: | character cannot be added to hexadecimal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XElement.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns *a string that contains all of the text content of this element*, but you want to display just the concatenated value(s) of the [`XText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) child nodes **directly** owned by each `XElement`.  (These are the nodes that hold the actual [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax) of an element.)

This can be done as follows:

```
var docNew = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(doc);
foreach (var element in docNew.Root.Descendants())
{
    var textValue = string.Concat(element.Nodes().OfType<System.Xml.Linq.XText>().Select(tx => tx.Value));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", element.Name.ToString(), textValue));
}
```

This logic can be extracted into an extension method:

```
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static string LocalValue(this XContainer node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        return string.Concat(node.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(tx => tx.Value));
    }
}
```

And used as follows:

```
var textValue = element.LocalValue();
```

It prints the following:

```
FormValues: 
Others: 
Bank: 
Key: FirstKey
Value: FirstValue
Bank: 
Key: SecondKey
Value: SecondValue
Bank: 
Key: ThirdKey
Value: ThirdValue
Bank: 
Key: FourthKey
Value: FourthValue
Prob: ProbValue
URL: http://example.com/
Method: GET
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Fy0r5).

Comment: Wov! XText. Worked as expected.