# XML linq remove work like contains not equal

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to remove some elements in my xml. I have an exceptions list, and I'm using a `for loop` to try to delete some elements, but in some cases my code is removing two objects, even though in my list i only have one.

In my XElement I have some elements like:

- japr
- japrtest
- jli
- permtest-integrator
- permtest-pm
- permtest-service

And in my exceptionsList I have just

- japrtest

And in my second exceptionsList, for example, I have:

- permtest

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(XML);
IEnumerable<XElement> allActiveUsers = root.Elements("users").Elements("user").Where(user => bool.Parse(user.Element("active").Value) == true);
var duplicatedActiveUsers = from user in allActiveUsers group user by user.Element("email").Value into tmpUser where tmpUser.Count() > 1 select tmpUser.Key.ToString();
IEnumerable<XElement> activeUsers = allActiveUsers.Where(p => duplicatedActiveUsers.Contains(p.Element("email").Value));
Console.WriteLine($"== przed -> {activeUsers.Count()} ==");
foreach (XElement user in activeUsers) Console.WriteLine($"- {user.Element("name").Value}");

var exceptionsUsersOne = new[] { "japrtest" };
for (int i = 0; i < exceptionsUsers.Count(); i++)
{
    activeUsers.Where(p => p.Element("name").Value == exceptionsUsers[i]).Remove();
}

Console.WriteLine($"== po -> {activeUsers.Count()} ==");
```

When I run it with `exceptionsUsersOne = new[] { "japrtest" };`
I get  a list where both `japrtest` *and* `japr` are removed, which is not the behavior I want.

When I use `exceptionsUsersTwo = new[] { "permtest" };` I get a list where only `permtest` is removed, and `permtest-something` is unaffected.

So why is `activeUsers.Where(p => p.Element("name").Value == exceptionsUsers[i]).Remove()` working like that?

Part of XML

```
<directories>
(...)
</directories>
<users>
    <user>
      <directoryId>32769</directoryId>
      <id>3474722</id>
      <name>japr</name>
      <createdDate>2018-03-13T11:04:16Z</createdDate>
      <updatedDate>2019-03-22T07:48:46Z</updatedDate>
      <active>true</active>
      <firstName>fName</firstName>
      <lastName>lName</lastName>
      <displayName>fName lName</displayName>
      <email>JUser@contoso.pl</email>
    </user>
    <user>
      <directoryId>32769</directoryId>
      <id>4162330</id>
      <name>japrtest</name>
      <createdDate>2018-05-28T05:59:12Z</createdDate>
      <updatedDate>2019-03-06T19:30:57Z</updatedDate>
      <active>true</active>
      <firstName>fName</firstName>
      <lastName>lName</lastName>
      <displayName>fName lName</displayName>
      <email>JUser@contoso.pl</email>
    </user>
</users>
<groups>
(...)
</groups>
```

Comment: My *guess* is that, since [`XElement.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the text content of all descendant nodes, you're accidentally deleting a parent node.  To get just the immediate value of an `XElement` see e.g. [XDocument Descendants() displays all child values in the parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28614385/3744182).

Comment: Change for loop.  When you have items 4,5,6 and you delete 5 item 6 becomes 5.  So you must start at end of list and move towards beginning : for (int i = exceptionsUsers.Count() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)

Comment: @dbc i added part of xml and made some test, when i remove the Remove() i just show element - i get one record, so I add another temp list with id and stil code remove two node...

Comment: If you change it to `exceptionsUsersOne = new[] { "japr" };` does it still remove both?